# How do I invert the colours of the background image using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to invert the colours of the background image given below.

```css
html {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 64 64" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"%3E%3Cpath d="M8 16c4.418 0 8-3.582 8-8s-3.582-8-8-8-8 3.582-8 8 3.582 8 8 8zm0-2c3.314 0 6-2.686 6-6s-2.686-6-6-6-6 2.686-6 6 2.686 6 6 6zm33.414-6l5.95-5.95L45.95.636 40 6.586 34.05.636 32.636 2.05 38.586 8l-5.95 5.95 1.414 1.414L40 9.414l5.95 5.95 1.414-1.414L41.414 8zM40 48c4.418 0 8-3.582 8-8s-3.582-8-8-8-8 3.582-8 8 3.582 8 8 8zm0-2c3.314 0 6-2.686 6-6s-2.686-6-6-6-6 2.686-6 6 2.686 6 6 6zM9.414 40l5.95-5.95-1.414-1.414L8 38.586l-5.95-5.95L.636 34.05 6.586 40l-5.95 5.95 1.414 1.414L8 41.414l5.95 5.95 1.414-1.414L9.414 40z" fill="%239C92AC" fill-opacity="0.4" fill-rule="evenodd"/%3E%3C/svg%3E');
}
```

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/invert-colors-css Does it help?

Answer (score 3):

Apply the coloration to the background and use white color for SVG. You don't really need transparency since you are dealing with the html element so there is nothing behind.

```css
html {
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 64 64" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"%3E%3Cpath d="M8 16c4.418 0 8-3.582 8-8s-3.582-8-8-8-8 3.582-8 8 3.582 8 8 8zm0-2c3.314 0 6-2.686 6-6s-2.686-6-6-6-6 2.686-6 6 2.686 6 6 6zm33.414-6l5.95-5.95L45.95.636 40 6.586 34.05.636 32.636 2.05 38.586 8l-5.95 5.95 1.414 1.414L40 9.414l5.95 5.95 1.414-1.414L41.414 8zM40 48c4.418 0 8-3.582 8-8s-3.582-8-8-8-8 3.582-8 8 3.582 8 8 8zm0-2c3.314 0 6-2.686 6-6s-2.686-6-6-6-6 2.686-6 6 2.686 6 6 6zM9.414 40l5.95-5.95-1.414-1.414L8 38.586l-5.95-5.95L.636 34.05 6.586 40l-5.95 5.95 1.414 1.414L8 41.414l5.95 5.95 1.414-1.414L9.414 40z" fill="white" fill-rule="evenodd"/%3E%3C/svg%3E'),
  rgba(156, 146, 172, 0.4);
}
```